# Conditionally include JS files in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, gruntjs, minify

I explain what I want to be able to do :

I'm developing an Angular application (not sure that's matter) and I'm also using a Gruntfile to minify my JavaScript code.

In a first part, the thing is when I'm developing, I don't want my index.html file to include the "compiled" version of my JavaScript code but all my JavaScript files. Because I don't want to relaunch the grunt command every time I want to test any modification.

In a second part, I want that the "compiled" version doesn't include all my JS files but only my compiled version for production purpose.

Is there any way to do that? If I was developing a C++ application, I would implement such a plain mecanism :

```
#ifdef DEBUG
   // include all JS files
#else
   // include only the compiled JS file
#endif
```

Comment: where do you executing the grunt command?

Comment: In the root directory of my Angular application, which the one where there are my index.html and Gruntfile.js files.

Comment: i mean when do you call `grunt`

Comment: Every time I want to test my application because my index.html file includes the compiled JS file. A manual solution would be to comment/uncomment the `<script>` tags every time I want to make a debug or release version but I integrated Grunt to my project in order to avoid such manipulation.

Comment: Yes, this possible using a grunt plugin. No, we cannot provide links to one such plugin.

Comment: @KevinB Thanks for your answer but what do you mean when you say you 'cannot provide links to one such plugin' ?

Comment: they become stale and out of date, so it's not very useful to do so.

Comment: Ok so without speaking of grunt plugin, there is no simple solution to conditionally include JS files in HTML?

Comment: well, i mean, you could theoretically write code that does what the grunt plugin does i guess, but there's no real point. https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=grunt+html

Answer (score -1):

if you execute the grant manually then you can create two tasks in grunt

1. for debugging
2. for production

you can read more about creating tasks in [this link](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't help me. I know how to use Grunt. The minification works well. The thing is, like the title of my question said, I want to conditionally include JS scripts in my index.html file according to the fact I want a debug or production version. I think this isn't a Grunt question but a HTML one. But if you have a Grunt solution to do that, please let me know.

Comment: can you append your gruntfile.js